# Script , Desplazar una figura de caracteres con bash hacia la derecha segun un numero X

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell-script

Necesito realizar el ejercicio 2 si fuera posible también de momento ya tengo hecho el código de la primera Les adjunto los enunciados y mi código
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no adjuntes imágenes. Adjunta el texto para que sea más fácil ayudarte. Y acá no hacemos tareas. Adjunta tu progreso y describe en qué tienes dificultad, no pongas simplemente la orden del ejercicio. Checa [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Simplemente, he preguntado para saber como se ponian espacios, a la figura que ya tengo de salida para desviarla hacia la derecha es la pregunta principal y puse de momento ya que sigo con ello no creo que sea mucho y simplemente creo que es 1 linea de codigo, a la vez decirle que adjunte mi progreso con una captura

Comment: No es mucho, pero al menos copialo a texto. Para que "agregar" esa línea de código no haya que "copiar" toda la imagen.